# LINQ to SQL Intersect Query Failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a Frequently Asked Question (FAQ) database with columns: id, Question, Answer, Category, and Keywords.

I want to take input from a user and search my database for matches. I ultimately want to take the search string and retrieve all records where **any** of the search string is found in either the Question **or** Keyword columns.

Since I'm relatively new at Linq to Sql, I'm trying to get just a single column search working first, and then try to get to a double column search. My code is still failing. I've seen other posts similar the topic, but the recommended solutions do not work exactly for my situation. Attempts to tweak those solutions have failed.

**Problematic portion of my code:**

```
private FAQViewModel getSearchResultFAQs(string search)
    {
        FAQViewModel vm = new FAQViewModel();
        vm.isSearch = true;

        string[] searchTerms = search.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        //var ques = db.FAQs.Where(q => q.Keywords.Intersect(searchTerms).Any());
        var ques = db.FAQs.Where(q => searchTerms.Any(t => q.Keywords.Contains(t)));
        List<FAQ> list = new List<FAQ>();

        foreach(var qs in ques)
        {
            FAQ f = new FAQ();
            f.Question = qs.Question;
            f.Answer = qs.Answer;
            f.Category = qs.Category;
            f.Keywords = qs.Keywords;
            f.id = qs.id;

            list.Add(f);
        }

        CategoryModel cm = new CategoryModel();
        cm.faqs = list;

        vm.faqs.Add(cm);

        return vm;
    }
```

This code fails. `q.Keywords` is underlined in red stating

> string does not contain a definition for 'Intersect'

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

### EDIT:

I commented out the bad line of code and used Gilad's first recommendation. I now get the following error:

"Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator."

It doesn't like the foreach codeblock:

```
foreach(var qs in ques)
```

I'm really out of my depth here but its so close to working.

Comment: What is the type of `Keywords`? Is it a single string? Can you provide an example of data?

Comment: Did any of the answers solved your question? Also it is still worth clarifying the questions in my comment above for future readers

Comment: @GiladGreen I attempted both of the recommendations you posted below. I get errors with both. You are correct the Keywords will contain several strings in one field. Since posting this question I have since had to modify my code a bit, which I have updated above. I'll include more info in my edit.